# LibVLC/LibvlcSharp/Windows RTSP -- Is There A Way To Tell if a Camera has hung?

Tags: windows, rtsp, libvlc, libvlcsharp

Using LibVLC/LibVLCSharp in Windows (Winforms) and using RTSP occasionally a camera will hang. Whatever the cause it is worth disposing of the MediaPlayer, creating a new one and trying again. This usually works.

However, it is difficult to tell if the libraries have a way of telling when a hang has taken place. Presumably it should be relatively easy for the library to tell that new frames have stopped coming in or if a socket has died.  If there is an event that tells me this I can't determine that from the documentation.

These kind of events are random, and they may occur only after several hours (or days).  Therefore experimentation is difficult.

Tried subscribing to pretty much every reasonable event and looked to see if one is hit. Nothing relevant appeared to be happening.

Comment: Is the error encountered event firing? The Stopped event? Is your WinForms app losing internet connection? Any relevant logs?